# Partial differential equation involving Heat Conduction Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know the solution for the given below Heat Conduction problem which involves the following boundary conditiion:

$$\begin{cases}
u_{t} - a^{2}u_{xx} = 0\\
u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) =0\\
u(x,0) = f(x).
\end{cases}$$

The solution for this problem is:
$$u(x,t) = \sum b_{n}\exp({-n^{2}a^{2}t)}\sin(nx).
$$

I want to know if I change the boundary condition in the second equation to some non zero value, will my eigenvalues just shift by that amount or will there be some changes in the solution of $u(x,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the BC then now the eigenfunctions with the homogeneous BCs don't satisfy the BCs, so there is no way to sum them up to get a solution to the BVP. But as in linear algebra, we can write the solution as a particular solution $u_p$ to the PDE with the BCs and the wrong initial condition, plus a homogeneous solution $u_h$ which solves the PDE with homogeneous BCs. $u_h$ will just be of the form that you wrote, except that $b_n$ will be determined by the initial condition for $u_h$, which involves both $f$ and the $u_p$ that you picked.

In the case of the heat equation with constant Dirichlet BCs on an interval, this turns out to be easy, because you can take $u_p(x,t)$ to be a fixed linear function of $x$ not depending on $t$ (why?)

Comment: But the eigenvalue will be $n^{2} + \alpha$? where $\alpha$ is the non zero value of the second boundary condition?

Comment: @ManishSahu No, the eigenvalues you use will be the same. They only come into play when you go back to find the homogeneous solution.

Comment: So the Sturm Louville problem will have a different boundary condition and the final solution will be sum of homogenous and non-homogenous part?

Comment: @ManishSahu I think you are correct, though your statement is slightly vague so I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Vague in which part?

Comment: @ManishSahu I'm not sure which Sturm-Liouville problem, exactly, you are talking about: the problem for $u$ or the problem for $u_h$. The problem for $u_h$ has homogeneous BCs, which are different from the inhomogeneous BCs in the problem for $u$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57070/discussion-between-manish-sahu-and-ian).